# Notice (8): Undefined variable en cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Cuando actualicé los cambios a la vista me da este error:

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: gestor [APP\View\Vistas\browser2.ctp, line 133]

He revisado arriba y abajo y nada.. me sigue dando el mismo error...

Similar a esto lo tengo en otra vista browser1.ctp y me funciona perfectamente...

Si alguien me da un norte....

Gracias

Aquí les dejo el code... la línea 133 en el original aquí es la 35

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th></th>';
    foreach ($campos as $campo => $nombre){
        echo '<th>'.$paginator->sort($campo, $nombre).'</th>';
    }
echo '</tr>';
foreach ($leads as $lead){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $this->Html->link(
        'Editar',
        '#',
        array('class' => 'edit_button', 'target' => '',"onclick"=>'openWindow("'.$lead['Vista']['id'].'","90%","100%");')
    );  
    echo '</td>';

    foreach ($campos as $campo => $nombre){
        if (is_numeric ($lead['Vista'][$campo]) or in_array($campo,$dates)) $clase='numeric';
        else $clase='texto';
        if (in_array($campo,$modificables))  $clase='desplegable';

        echo '<td class="'.$clase.'">';

        if (in_array($campo,$modificables)){
    if ($campo == 'valid_status') {
      echo '<form action="javascript:save_text('.$lead['Vista']['id'].')">';
      echo $this->Form->input('valid_status', array('div'=>false, 'class'=>'selection_'.$lead['Vista']['id'],'label'=>false, 'selected'=>$lead['Vista'][$campo], 
        'name'=>$lead['Vista']['id'].'_select','options' => array($status),'onChange'=>'this.form.submit()'));
      echo '<div class="div_sta_'.$lead['Vista']['id'].'"></div>';
      echo '</form>';
    } else {
      echo '<form action="javascript:save_gestor('.$lead['Vista']['id'].')">';
      echo $this->Form->input('id_gestor', array('div'=>false, 'class'=>'gestor_'.$lead['Vista']['id'],'label'=>false, 'selected'=>$lead['Vista'][$campo], 
        'name'=>$lead['Vista']['id'].'_select','options' => array($gestor),'onChange'=>'this.form.submit()')); // ESTA ES LA LÍNEA DEL ERROR
      echo '<div class="div_ges_'.$lead['Vista']['id'].'"></div>';
      echo '</form>';
    }
        }else if (in_array($campo,$dates)){
            if ($lead['Vista'][$campo]=='') echo 'N/A';
            else echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($lead['Vista'][$campo]));
        }else echo $lead['Vista'][$campo];

        echo '</td>';

    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Y la vista se renderea igual o se interrumpe el request?

Comment: *la línea 133 en el original aquí es la 35*... Podrías haber indicado con un comentario `//Esta es la línea 133` y así no nos obligas a contar 35 líneas. La variable **`$gestor`** ¿dónde la has declarado? La usas...  `'name'=>$lead['Vista']['id'].'_select','options' => array($gestor),'onChange'=>'this.form.submit()'));`, pero no la declaras.

Comment: vale, gracias... no me había dado cuenta.. y yo buscando otras cosas..

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando la variable gestor y no le has asignado un valor.

```
echo $this->Form->input('id_gestor', array('div'=>false, 'class'=>'gestor_'.$lead['Vista']['id'],'label'=>false, 'selected'=>$lead['Vista'][$campo], 
        'name'=>$lead['Vista']['id'].'_select','options' => array($gestor),'onChange'=>'this.form.submit()'));
```

Debes inicializar la variable `$gestor` antes de usarla

```
$gestor = 'valorpordefecto';
```

Luego ya puedes.

```
echo $this->Form->input('id_gestor', array('div'=>false, 'class'=>'gestor_'.$lead['Vista']['id'],'label'=>false, 'selected'=>$lead['Vista'][$campo], 
        'name'=>$lead['Vista']['id'].'_select','options' => array($gestor),'onChange'=>'this.form.submit()'));
```

Comment: Gracias amigo. Resuelto el problema... Gracias